# How to program notifications like google keep?

Tags: android, notifications, reminders

I need notifications like Google keep which run at a specified time even when app is not running. I mean reminder notifications, which remind according to the time set. There are lot of applications which do this like ColorNote.

I know how to create a notification. I don't know how to schedule it a later time , even when app is not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `Service` to keep going while your app is not running, and set an alarm using `AlarmManager` to schedule your action.

Read about the right way to do repeating alarms here:
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

And about `Service`s here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html